# JOIN repeated rows django ORM python

Tags: python, django, orm

I have the following model:

```
class Cierre(models.Model): 
    bus=models.ForeignKey(Bus)
    ruta=models.ForeignKey(Ruta,editable=False) 
    conductor=models.ForeignKey(Conductor,editable=False)       
    total_pasajeros = models.IntegerField(editable=False)
    total_viaje = models.FloatField(editable=False)
```

And, with this data:

```
Ruta    Bus     conductor   Total pasajeros Valor total viaje
1       qwe789  1111111     50              107500.0
1       qwe789  1111111     100             215000.0
2       qwe789  1111111     50              102500.0
```

I need if the column 'Ruta' and column 'conductor' is been repeat, to join    respective column 'valor total viaje'. The result I want is this:

```
 Ruta   Bus     conductor   Total pasajeros Valor total viaje
    1       qwe789  1111111     50          322500.0     
    2       qwe789  1111111     50          102500.0
```

I have tried:

```
cierre = Cierre.objects.annotate(sales=Sum('ruta'))
```

And:

```
cierre = Cierre.objects.annotate(
            count_ruta = Count('ruta')
        ).order_by(
            'ruta'
        ).filter(
            count_ruta__gt=1
        ).distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cierre = Cierre.objects.distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

This query seems to do what you want:

```
Cierre.objects.values("ruta", "bus").annotate(total_viaje = Sum("total_viaje"))
```

It yields:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'bus': u'qwe789', 'ruta': 1L, 'total_viaje': 322500.0},
    {'bus': u'qwe789', 'ruta': 2L, 'total_viaje': 102500.0}
]>
```

This query does, however, ignore the column "Total pasajeros", because in your example you arbitrarily chose to use the value 50 instead of 100 for the row with ruta=1, so I assumed it was irrelevant. If you also want to add up the values of "total_pasajeros", you can just add another .annotate() and SUM that column too :)